# Transferring the ownership of object from one unique_ptr to another unique_ptr in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move-semantics

In `C++11` we can transfer the ownership of an object to another `unique_ptr` using `std::move()`. After the ownership transfer, the smart pointer that ceded the ownership becomes `null` and `get()` returns `nullptr.`

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int(42));
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::move(p1); // Transfer ownership
```

What are the situations where this will be useful as it is transferring the ownership to another `unique_ptr`?

Comment: That's it. The smart pointers in the standard library should not really be seen as pointers that are automatically free'd, but in terms of *ownership*. Do you have some data that can only be "owned" by a single entity, then use unique pointers.

Comment: It's useful when you are working with non-copyable data like threads or sockets and you need to replace it from one place to another (for example, to put it into the vector).

Answer (score 54):

The following situations involve transferring ownership from one `unique_ptr` to another: returning from a function, and passing as a parameter to a function like a constructor.

Say you have some polymorphic type `Animal`:

```
struct Animal {
  virtual ~Animal() {}
  virtual void speak() = 0;
};
```

with concrete subclasses `Cat` and `Dog`:

```
struct Cat : Animal {
  void speak() override { std::cout << "Meow!\n"; }
};

struct Dog : Animal {
  void speak() override { std::cout << "Woof!\n"; }
};
```

And you want a simple factory that creates a pet based on a required value of obedience. Then the factory must return a pointer. We want the pet factory to transfer ownership of the created pet to the caller so a reasonable return type is `std::unique_ptr<Animal>`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> createPet(double obedience) {
  if (obedience > 5.0)
    return std::make_unique<Dog>();
  return std::make_unique<Cat>();
}
```

Now, say we want to create a `House` that will own the pet then we might want to pass the pet into the constructor of the `House`. There is some debate ([see comments on this blog post](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html)) about how best to pass a `unique_ptr` to a constructor but it would look something like this:

```
class House {
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Animal> pet_;
 public:
  House(std::unique_ptr<Animal> pet) : pet_(std::move(pet)) {}
};
```

We have passed the `unique_ptr` into the constructor and have then "moved" it to the member variable.

The calling code could look something like:

```
  auto pet = createPet(6.0);
  House house(std::move(pet));
```

After constructing the `House`, the `pet` variable will be `nullptr` because we have transferred ownership of the pet to the `House`.

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a623e0046aec7cc8)</kbd>

Comment: Is it better to change the constructor to take an r-value reference to unique_ptr? E.g. House(std::unique_ptr<Animal>&& pet). Then you wouldn't need the std::move() call in the initializer list for pet_?

Comment: @jfritz42 An r-value reference is itself an l-value so you still need the `std::move`.  [Try it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42b8222989a16651).

Comment: Good point! BTW this seems like a new C++ idiom. I wonder if it's been given a name by anybody yet. The "transfer ownership idiom"?

Comment: Note that you can also do move assignment: `uptr1 = std::move(uptr2)`

Answer (score 8):

for example if you call a function you can `move` your `unique_ptr` in the parameter list so it can be a part of your function signature

```
foo ( std::unique_ptr<T>&& ptr )
```

you can call foo with

```
foo( std::move(myPtr) );
```

Note that `std::move` is an unconditional cast and `unique_ptr` is an object with a state, and a part of that state is the pointer that that `unique_ptr` is managing, with `std::move` you are casting the entire object, you are not really changing anything about ownership, there is nothing peculiar about `std::unique_ptr` while using `std::move` because `std::move` doesn't really care about anything specific, as I said it is an unconditional cast and `unique_ptr` simply gets casted, the entire object that is an instance of type `unique_ptr<T>` is casted .

If you want to talk about a transfer of ownership of the object pointed by your `unique_ptr`, you should consider the `swap` provided by [`std::unique_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) itself .

Comment: `unique_ptr` transfers ownership of the managed object when you `move` into another `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that's semantically incorrect, `move` doesn't do anything, it's just a cast, its semantic is about mutating an expression into an rvalue, non about trasferring ownership in the the case of `unique_ptr`, when the function call will happen, that `unique_ptr` will be moved, that's a side effect and if your purpose is to change ownership this is the most cryptic way of doing it with the wrong semantic, just don't do it, use `swap`, it has the right semantic and it just does what you want .

Comment: To be honest I'm not quite sure what you mean. But what do you think happens when you `push_back` a `unique_ptr` into a `vector` using `move`?

Comment: @user1308004,  whilst it is true that `std::move` doesn't actually move,  it just prepares it to be moved from, that distinction is not important in most cases hence why they decided to call it `std::move`. I don't see what is cryptic about using `std::move` to a transfer ownership from one `unique_ptr` into another. That's what `unique_ptr` has a move constructor and move assignment for.

Comment: @ChrisDrew is cryptic because `std::move` is general, it's in the `std` namespace ready for everyone to use, it's also a cast, which means it doesn't express any intent beside a change of type. Don't you think that `swap` is like a magnitude better than a generic cast ? `swap` does what it says it does, it's just designed to do that, has the right semantics and there is even a specialized `swap` for `unique_ptr` .

Comment: If you want to use `swap` to transfer ownership in a function call you have to pass by non-const reference which does not express intent at all. Passing by value or rvalue-ref much better expresses the intent.

Comment: @ChrisDrew what a `const` reference of an `unique_ptr` gives you ? It just prevents possible optimizations, why you even need `const` when your are using `unique_ptr` ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting passing by const reference. I'm suggesting pass by value or rvalue-ref.