# How to convert a raw pointer to unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I have this sample code:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> some_function() {
    //I cannot use unique ptr here becuase it will get freed when the function return i guess
    Derived* derived = new Derived;
    return static_cast<std::unique_ptr<Base>>(derived);
}
```

Is using `static_cast` here is a good solution?
Are there other alternatives to return `unique_ptr`?

And

```
return std::unique_ptr<Command>(derived);
```

if I return like this, will the ptr be freed at the end of the return expression since it is anynomous?

And what is the workaround if I don't want to use raw pointers in `Derived* derived = new Derived;`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transferring the ownership of object from one unique\_ptr to another unique\_ptr in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318506/transferring-the-ownership-of-object-from-one-unique-ptr-to-another-unique-ptr-i)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I cannot use unique ptr here becuase it will get freed when the function return i guess

You can simply return it and the ownership of the raw pointer stored in the smart pointer will be transferred from your local variable to the `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Base> some_function() {
    auto derived = std::make_unique<Derived>();

    // use derived in here ...

    return derived; // and return it by value
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/45Pc6d6ao)